# Put the \encl at the bottom of the page (lettre class)

Tags: vertical-alignment, letters, lettre

Using the `lettre` document class, I want to place the enclosures *automatically* at the bottom of the page, like this :

[image]

This is the default behavior :

[image]

This is the code I used to get the first picture (with the enclosures at the bottom) :

```
\documentclass[romand]{lettre}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\name{Mister Z}


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Company X\\
Mister Y\\
Address\\
Town}

\conc{Business contract}

\opening{Dear Sir,}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, % and so on..

\closing{Kind regards,}
\vspace{60mm} % This is what I want to be automatic (adaptative)
\encl{Contract}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

I'd like to replace `\vspace{60mm}` by something which would automatically take all free space like `\vfill`. But `\vfill` does not do what I want here, I think this is because the letter is written inside the *letter* environment, which probably does not take the whole page. I tried to find a solution by looking at the `lettre.cls` file, but with no success.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (`{}`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strategy is correct, but the `lettre` class does a couple of tricky/not nice things. The class adds `\stopletter` (defined as `\vskip0ptplus1filll`) at the end of the letter. That is a `filll` with 3 l's which swamps all the other stretchable glue. If you replace `\vspace{60mm}` with `\vskip0ptplus1filll` then you enclosure will be halfway to the bottom of the page since you add some 3-l stretch instead of the 2-l stretch of `\vfill`. If you also redefine `\stopletter` to not add space, then the enclosure will be at the bottom of the page. Putting it all together gives

```
\documentclass[romand]{lettre}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\name{Mister Z}


\def\stopletter{}%

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Company X\\
Mister Y\\
Address\\
Town}

\conc{Business contract}

\opening{Dear Sir,}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, % and so on..

\closing{Kind regards,}
\vskip0ptplus1filll
\encl{Contract}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In order to not having to add this in each letter, I added these 3 lines in my "institute" (.ins) file (the one called by `\institute{}`) :  
`\def\stopletter{}  
\let\enclold\encl  
\renewcommand\encl[1]{\vskip0ptplus1filll\enclold{#1}}`